# C# Switch on enums

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an enum:

```
public enum Status 
{ 
    Incomplete = 1, Complete = 2, Cancelled = 3, Deleted = 4 
}
```

Now on a certain page I wish to list this enum in a checkboxlist. This would be fine except that I want the text of each checkbox to display different text than the enum.

i.e the check boxes should say:

"Not Processed" instead of "Incomplete"

"Processed" instead of "Complete"

"Void" instead of "Cancelled"

Is it possible to put this enum in a foreach and then switch on the status and update the text. Like so:

```
var statuses = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Status));
foreach (var status in statuses)))
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case Status.Complete.ToString(): 
        status = "Processed";
        break; ...etc                 
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C# has a language feature that directly addresses your question. [Here's an article](http://www.ytechie.com/2008/05/creating-user-friendly-strings-for-enum-values.html) that gives you the complete details.

The short version: apply extension attribute values to each value:

```
enum OrderStatus  
{  
    [EnumValueData(Name="New Order")]  
    NewOrder = 1,  
    [EnumValueData(Name="In Process")]  
    Processing = 2,  
    [EnumValueData(Name="Shipped")]  
    Shipped = 3  
}
```

Then apply said values to your radio-buttons, listbox or whatever:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> GetListItems(Type enumType)  
{  
    if (!enumType.IsEnum)  
        throw new ApplicationException("GetListItems does not support non-enum types");  
    Dictionary<int, string> list = new Dictionary<int, string>();  
    foreach(FieldInfo field in enumType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Public))  
    {  
        int value;  
        string display;  
        value = (int)field.GetValue(null);  
        display = Enum.GetName(enumType, value);  
        foreach(Attribute currAttr in field.GetCustomAttributes(true))  
        {  
            EnumValueDataAttribute valueAttribute = currAttr as EnumValueDataAttribute;  
            if (valueAttribute != null)  
                display = valueAttribute.Name;  
        }  
        list.Add(value, display);  
    }  
    return list;  
}
```

Comment: Seems to me this is creating a new attribute (EnumValueDataAttribute) for which one already exists (System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute).  It works but I question why you would create a new one rather than use DescriptionAttribute?

Comment: @TLiebe - good point. I am the victim of years of artificially imposed coding standards. This is the way the developers whom I joined had been doing it. I don't break pattern; makes for nasty code reviews! :)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [Description attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute%28VS.71%29.aspx) in the System.ComponentModel class to assign a text description to each enum value.  You can then set the text property by iterating through the enum and getting the Description attribute of each instead of using a switch.

```
public enum Status
{
    [Description("Not Processed")] Incomplete = 1,
    [Description("Processed")] Complete = 2,
    [Description("Void")] Cancelled = 3,
    Deleted = 4
}
```

You could then use something like the following to get the description of a single enum value (or modify it to return a Dictionary of  as Bob showed in his example):

```
    public static string GetEnumDescription ( Object value )
    {
        try
        {
            Type objType = value.GetType();
            FieldInfo fldInf = objType.GetField( Enum.GetName( objType, value ) );

            Object[ ] attributes = fldInf.GetCustomAttributes( false );

            if ( attributes.Length > 0 )
            {
                DescriptionAttribute descAttr = ( DescriptionAttribute )attributes[ 0 ];
                return descAttr.Description;
            }
            else
            {
                return value.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: May I nitpick?  Just wanted to point out that, in "real" code, you probably want something more robust than attributes[ 0 ].  Also, I'm pretty sure that try/catch pure evil, but there are other threads on that subject.  </nitpicking> I will try this solution in the future.  Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Constructive nitpicking is always welcome.  Your points are good and while I'll admit the code is my own, I'll defend myself with the (admittedly poor) excuse that it's old and from some of the very first .NET code I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your Modification string in an array and then use the enum index to access the array element.